# php gd copy image quality, falls, why?

Tags: php, gd

i want your help, i do copy image on white background and quality of my image, falls.

Tell me please from which it can be.

This original image.

[image: original image]

It code save image and copy

```
$orig_width = imagesx( $source_image );
$orig_height = imagesy( $source_image );

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
imagecopyresized($new_image, $source_image,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    $imgW, $imgH,
    $orig_width, $orig_height);

// $source_image = imagescale($source_image, $imgW, $imgH,  IMG_BICUBIC_FIXED);


$im = @imagecreate( $cropW, $cropH - 40 )
or die("Невозможно создать поток изображения");

$background_color = imagecolorallocate( $im, 255, 255, 255);

$sx = imagesx( $new_image );
$sy = imagesy( $new_image );

imagecopy($im, $new_image, $imgX1, $imgY1, 0, 0, imagesx($new_image),             imagesy($new_image));

// $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
// imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "Простая Текстовая Строка", $text_color);


imagejpeg( $im, $output_filename.$type, 100 );
```

And it image for this code PHP GD

[image: final image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$im = @imagecreate( $cropW, $cropH - 40 )
```

Use:

```
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor( $cropW, $cropH - 40 )
```

Answer (score 0):

And after,not to lose background color white, need write so.

```
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $background_color);
```